# Is there a tool to log call stacks when a specified application's UI hangs?

Tags: .net, debugging

a customer of ours is experiencing UI hangs with one of our applications every few weeks. Since the customer is located quite a distance away and when this problem occurs there is a high chance that there is no competent personnel nearby, I'm looking for a way to automatically log the call stacks of all threads of the process (or a dump) after the UI hasn't responded for several seconds. It also would be cool if the tool would be able to log the call stacks in a specific interval during a freeze.

Is there a tool like this? Do you have any other tips how I could debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `procdump` with the `-h` parameter (and it might be useful to also use `-ma`, but that's up to your needs). This will produce a complete memory dump as soon as the application stops responding for at least 5 seconds. You can then open the dump in WinDbg or Visual Studio. Just make sure you have the exact same version of the .NET framework (if not, copy the whole Framework folder from the client's computer).

You can get ProcDump here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx. It's a very useful tool you can use to debug client issues (including unexpected exceptions etc.). Using the dump you basically get as close as possible to the state the application was in before the crash / hang / whatever happened, including heap data, stack data, call stack, local variables etc.